# How to start multiple external programs like FEM solver concurrently with limited time in Qt or pure c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I tried QThreadpool, QtConcurrent but I found it difficult to do "timeout" feature in Qt.

For example, I want to start 40 process to finished one task, then I create 40 threads. For each thread, I create a QProcess object and I find it difficult to count time because the timeout variable for QProcess is counted in millisecond and the type is int.

Then I tried the code below for each task , but sometimes it works, sometimes it blocked without any notification. I have no idea.

I find Java is good for it, but does anyone know how to add a long time timeout in Qt? Or a better idea?

```
   QProcess *maxwell_process = new QProcess;

    maxwell_process->start(maxwellExePath, args);

    connect(maxwell_process, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
        [&](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
        printf("process stopped");
        this->stopped = true;
    });
    t_ini = clock();
    while (1) {

        Sleep(100);
        t_fin = clock();
        secs = (double)(t_fin - t_ini);
        secs = secs / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        if (solution->getTimeOutValue() == -1) {
            std::cout<<"init population time"<<std::endl;
            if (this->stopped) {
                disconnect(maxwell_process);
                std::cout<<"init population time "<<secs<<std::endl;
                solution->setTime(secs);
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (secs > solution->getTimeOutValue()) {
                disconnect(maxwell_process);
                printf("timeout");
                maxwell_process->kill();
                solution->setTime(secs);
                break;
            }
        }
                QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }
```

Comment: QProcess has nothing to do with multithreaded. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding,  I edited the question.

Comment: Where is the `solution` object coming from?

Comment: is the code above the only code which is executed in the thread?

Comment: Don’t use a while loop and/or Threads. Qt has a event loop as you have figured out. Use QTimer to send a timeout event.

Comment: No, the code above is a part of whole project. I will try QTimer :)@manni66